# Deploy large files to Artifactory repo from .NET Windows Service

Tags: vb.net, artifactory

I have been working for a couple of weeks now trying to deploy artifacts to an Artifacory repo using a .NET Windows Service.
I have tried WebClient, HTTPWebResquest, and now RestSharp.

These all work fine on small files, but large files (>80MB) fail to deploy.
I recieve errors such as "The request was aborted; The Request Was Canceled"
and System.IO.OutOfMemory Exception.

I have my Artifactory Max File Upload size set to 100GB.

Any help/insight/direction on deploying LARGE artifacts to Artifactory though .NET will be GREATLY Appreciated!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Basically, all I need to know is:
Has anyone deployed LARGE artifacts to Artifactory via .NET?
If so, what language and libraries were used?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet showing what you are currently trying to do? There are various implementation in Java, GoLang and other languages which uploads files to Artifactory without such issues, so I assume it has something to do with the way you tried implementing it